# How to set multiple select options by default from array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to retrieve options/values from my database in the from of an array i would like to set these option/values as selected by default in a multiple select list and display them to the user where they will be able to updated their data if necessary.

```
//data in database
$mytitle = array(
    'Arbitrator',
    'Attorney',
    'Student',
    'Other'
); 

//data for multiple select
$title = array(
    'Judge' ,
    'Magistrate' ,
    'Attorney' ,
    'Arbitrator',
    'Title Examiner' ,
    'Law Clerk','Paralegal' ,
    'Intern' ,
    'Legal Assistant',
    'Judicial Assistant',
    'Law Librarian' ,
    'Law Educator' ,
    'Attorney',
    'Student',
    'Other'
);

echo "<select name='title[]' multiple='multiple'>";

$test = implode(',', $mytitle);

for ($i=0; $i<=14; $i++) {
    if($test == $title[$i]) {
        echo "<option selected value='$title[$i]'>$title[$i]</option>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<option value='$title[$i]'>$title[$i]</option>";
    }
}

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have a logic error. Try this as your loop:

```
foreach ($title as $opt) {
    $sel = '';
    if (in_array($opt, $mytitle)) {
        $sel = ' selected="selected" ';
    }
    echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $opt . '">' . $opt . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: small modification, if u kept the code this way, it will show all results as Selected. 
so what to do is `if (in_array($opt, $mytitle)) {
        $sel = ' selected="selected" ';
echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $opt . '">' . $opt . '</option>';
    }else{
echo '<option value="' . $opt . '">' . $opt . '</option>';
} `

Answer (score 0):

Use the in_array() function.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=14; $i++) {
  if(in_array($title[$i], $mytitle)){
    echo "<option selected value='$title[$i]'>$title[$i]</option>";
  }else {
    echo "<option value='$title[$i]'>$title[$i]</option>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with the help of jQuery where the select has the id test

```
$('#test option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/et3hH/)